# SSIS locking table while updating it

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactions, locking, etl

I have an SSIS package which when runs, updates a table. It is using a staging table and subsequently, uses slowly changing dimension table to load data into the warehouse. We have set it up as a SQL Agent job and it runs every two hours.

The isolation level of the package is serializable. The database isolation level is read committed.

The issue is that when this job runs, this job blocks that table and therefore, clients cannot run any reports. It blanks it out.

So what would be the best option for me to avoid it? clients need to see that data, meanwhile, we need to update the table every two hours.

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB4019092) - 11.0.6251.0 (X64)

Thanks.

Comment: Your clients are running reports from the staging table?   That's pretty much my definition of "not a staging table".

Comment: Hi, if you read carefully, it says subsequently, its using SCD into warehouse table. From staging to dimension table.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting "lock escalation". It's a feature, not a bug. 8-)

SQL Server combines large numbers of smaller locks into a table lock to improve performance.

If INSERT performance isn't an issue, you can do your data load in smaller chunks inside of transactions and commit after each chunk.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323630/how-to-resolve-blocking-problems-that-are-caused-by-lock-escalation-in

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to give your clients/reports access to a clone of your warehouse table.

Do your ETL into a table that no one else can read from, and when it is finished, switch the table with the clone.